# Why do I have to 'need' all models when testing models in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-qunit

I have three entities `Token - N:1 - User - N:1 - Company`. I let ember-cli to generate model tests and all of them failed. Thats somehow expected, since when testing Token it should need User so I added user into needs. Whats mysterious to me is why do I have to include Company as well? Will I have to include all of my models in every model test?

```
// tests/unit/models/token-test.js
import {moduleForModel, test} from 'ember-qunit';
moduleForModel('token', {
    needs: ['model:user', 'model:company']
});

test('it exists', function(assert) {
    var model = this.subject();
    // var store = this.store();
    assert.ok(!!model);
});

//models/token.js
user: DS.belongsTo('user')

//models/user.js
tokens: DS.hasMany('token')
company: DS.belongsTo('company')

//models/company.js
users: DS.hasMany('user')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your model definitions I can't know for sure (would you mind posting those?), but it seems like it's because your models have relationships between them. From the [Ember CLI website](http://www.ember-cli.com/#moduleformodelname-description-callbacks):

> Note: If the model you are testing has relationships to any other model, those must be specified through the needs property.

My guess is that your `token` model has relationships to both your `user` and `company` models. (Or your `token` is related to the `user`, and the `user` is related to the `company`.)

Ember CLI's goal for tests is for them to be as isolated as possible, so it doesn't load anything for you - you have to declare *all* dependencies. It seems like a pain, but it makes for much better unit tests.

Comment: The ```token``` is related to the ```user``` and the ```user``` is related to the ```company```. You are right, after adding another entity connected to company I found out that ```Token``` and ```User``` doesn't need it. So I don't have to need all models everywhere but just one or two levels of connections.